# How to verify the email exist or not in magento2 api

Tags: magento2, customer, magento2.4.1, customer-registration

How to verify the email exist or not using 3rd party api in magento2 while customer registration

thanks

Answer (score 1):

Action: POST

> URL: <Host_Url>/rest/default/V1/customers/isEmailAvailable

HEADER: NULL

Request Payload:

```
{
    "customerEmail": "test@test.com",
    "websiteId": "1" //OPTIONAL FIELD
}
```

Response: Boolean

Comment: can you send the full code

Comment: You can try to test this API on the postman.